# Razor compile and check templateName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

We are running aspnet_compiler as part of our build flow but it seems that it does not check if the referred templates actually exists.

Example:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Something, "Garbage")
```

In this case the compiler will not tell us this error. Is there a way to catch this error at compile time?

I know resharper can flag the error but we don't have resharper at out build server ATM.

Comment: At least you can write another exe, and check the case before build

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: @WillRay we are using mvc 4